# Error While dumping sql data into json in django

Tags: json, django, postgresql

I am quite new to django. I am trying to convert sql data fetched from a remote postgresql database into JSON so as to use it in react. But while dumping the data it throws as error.

```
`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'`
```

I tried many versions of dumping sql data into json like coneverting data into list and using RealDictCursor but each one of them throws a new error.

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .marketer import marketer
def marketer_list(request):
    return JsonResponse(marketer)
```

marketer.py (function to fetch data and establish the connection)

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
import json
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import RealDictCursor
def marketer(self):
    connection = psycopg2.connect(user = "db-user",
                                  password = "*****",
                                  host = "18.23.42.2",
                                  port = "5432",
                                  database = "db-name")
    cursor = connection.cursor(cursor_factory = RealDictCursor)
    postgreSQL_select_Query = "select id from auth_permission"
    result = cursor.execute(postgreSQL_select_Query)
    #print("Selecting rows from mobile table using cursor.fetchall")
    #mobile = dictfetchall(result)

    #items = [dict(zip([key[0] for key in cursor.description], row)) for 
    row in result] 
    return json.dumps(cursor.fetchall(), indent=2)
```

Error at Url page
    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
or 
in some other methods
     is not JSON serializable

Comment: Why aren't you using Django to connect to your database?  You shouldn't be using `psycopg2`